# Half page left blank before a new section when there is a big table

Tags: tables, floats, page-breaking

In my tex file, I have a table that takes a page to show. But this table always causes a page with a huge amount of blank space before the next section. Is there any way to fix this?

I have tried to change the position of the table from t to p to h, but these changes do not help.

[image]

Comment: No,that doesn't help.... it also create a weird formatting of the table (the table would extend out of the margin of the page)

Comment: It seems like your `table` is set just before a new sectional unit. Are you using anything in your preamble that forces floats to be set before some barrier? Can you provide code that replicates this behaviour?

Comment: As Werner pointed out, it would be helpful if you add your LaTeX code in the Question so we can find out the issue you are having and help you futher.

Comment: A mere screenshot is never helpful. Code that reproduces the screenshot for us, or a similar screenshot with the same behaviour, is helpful. And never use `[H]` as the positioning option.

Answer (score 3):

Your table environment appears to be about 2/3 of a page high. With the default settings that means that it is probably too large to go into `t` unless you do `!t`. So you end up with it on a page of its own (which will be following after the page it was encountered in the source). Thus, moving it earlier and/or using `!t` might help.

I recommend reading "How to influence the position of float environments like figure and table in LaTeX?" at https://www.latex-project.org/publications/ for some details how the float mechanism works and how it can be manipulated.